# Gravity Forms Anchor only on Front Page?

Tags: plugin-development, filters, frontpage, plugin-gravity-forms

I have a front page that is pretty long length-wise so I have enabled `add_filter("gform_confirmation_anchor", create_function("","return true;"));` in my `functions.php` file. This helps the Gravity Form return to form on validation or submission (which overrides the defaults which would normally just return you to the top of the page).

I am looking for a way to only execute this code on the front page...this is what I have tried (in my `functions.php` file):

```
if (is_front_page()) {
    add_filter("gform_confirmation_anchor", create_function("","return true;"));
}
```

But that continues to add the filter on every page...could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: [How to create a plugin that only operates on the home page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/how-to-create-a-plugin-that-only-operates-on-the-home-page)

I just had to wrap the filter in a function:

```
function gravity_forms() {
    if (is_front_page()) {
        add_filter("gform_confirmation_anchor", create_function("","return true;"));
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'gravity_forms');
```

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: One little improvement to add - WP has some handy little functions to return true, false etc. They are `__return_true()`, `__return_false()`, `__return_zero()`, `__return_empty_array()`, `__return_null()`, and `__return_empty_string()`. So, you can simplify your code by using: `add_filter( 'gform_confirmation_anchor', '__return_true' );`

Comment: Thank you for sharing, definitely going to adjust the code :-)